# How to create a razor page with valid entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

The packages are up to date, I have no error yet when I create a crud page with entity framework I get this error message. I searched on the internet but I don't think there is the same context.

And it is marked error when executing the generator of the selected code: "Unable to resolve service for type" Microsoft.EntityFramworkCore.DB.contextOptions [Fictum_Web.Data.DataContext] while attempting to activate Fictum_Web.Data.DataContext."

```
   public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<MessageM> MessagesM { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfv6E.png)

Comment: Hello AdamD, could you please explain a bit more what you are trying to acheive? In addition, if could explain the error in English so that it can be meaningful to all.

Comment: excuse me I had not noticed I will correct

Comment: @AdamD what you ask is described in the [Razor Pages Getting Started tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Have you checked it? You missed the `AddDbContext` call

Comment: Indeed it was necessary to call him I thought I had done it. Thanks